# Ruby on rails not loading layout responsive for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, responsive-design

Its been a Day since i am facing this issue . and i have no clue why this happening. i am trying to import a layout in the rails 4 application.
I am using `bootstrap.css` and `responsive.css`
i guess my `responsive.css` file is not working in my rails app

i can explain clearly by these images

when i load the layout by just clicking on the html file without the rails app this is the layout i am getting on mobile devices

[image]

and by importing the layout in the rails this is what i am getting

[image]

as by the rails app when it will run on mobile devices everything will look small
i am seeing no error in the browser console all my assets are loading correctly . but what i think this may be the error of

```
@media (max-width: px) {
}
```

but i am not sure .
`and i have already included <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />` in the head tag.
can someone please help me with this so my app can be perfectly responsive

Answer (score 3):

You should control the composition in mobile browsers.
Use the meta viewport tag in your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />    
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Comment: not sure why when i add this all the content came to the left side

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'` in your (probably 'application') layout (first argument can be any name of your css file)

Explanation from [api-dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag)

> The ‘media’ attribute will always be present and defaults to “screen”, so you must explicitly set it to “all” for the stylesheet(s) to apply to all media types.

Comment: @user4965201  interesting. it seems like your media queries doesn't work. make sure, that: file `responsive.css` imported in `application`, you can see the code in *inspector's **sources***, you don't have multiple `meta 'viewport'` tags, you don't have synthax errors

Comment: i have already required responsive in my application.css still the same error ... and when i don't require application.css in the layout rather including files one by one the code works perfectly . i know this is not how you do in Rails. :(